# Undefined property stdClass

Tags: php

why ??

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$users
>
> Filename: views/user_view.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\views\user_view.php Line: 10
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\users.php Line: 7
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: We are not able to answer your question if we can't see your code...

Answer (score 1):

You try to access a variable without it first being defined. If you define it first, you won't get an error.

```
<?php

$x = new stdClass();
$y = $x->z;   // gererates Notice in error_log


$x = new stdClass();
$x->z = 'assigned';    // now it is assigned
$y = $x->z;  // no error

// or you could make your own class
class Whatever
{
    public $z;
}

$x = new Whatever();
$y = $x->z;  // it's there whether a value has been assigned or not
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/hOThV